# How can I change button color on mouse hover in html

Tags: html

I want change the button color on mouse hover. I have the below code for button.

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="CENTER" class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0px;" width="33%" valign="middle">

        <a class="btn-primary" href="[http://www.google.com][1]" style="font-family: 'Arial,sans-serif', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 11px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #348eda; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-color: #348eda; border-style: solid; border-width: 3px 7px;">Google</a>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with css

```
a:hover { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `a:hover { ... CSS properties ... }` would work, but in your case the `anchor-tag` is given an inline css, so `:hover` selector in your CSS, would be overidden by your inline CSS (*which you have in `<a style='... CSS properties ...'></a>`*)

So suggest you to try as follows:

Giving the CSS properties in external CSS file(if you have) or as internal CSS(inside your `<head>...</head>`).

```css
a{
  font-family: 'Arial,sans-serif', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 11px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; line-height: 2; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: capitalize; background-color: #348eda; margin: 0; padding: 0; border-color: #348eda; border-style: solid; border-width: 3px 7px;
  }

a:hover
{
  background-color:#24659C;
  border-color:#24659C;
  }
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="CENTER" class="content-block" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 0px;" width="33%" valign="middle">

        <a class="btn-primary" href="[http://www.google.com][1]" style="">Google</a>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> **Side Note:** Also better if you could give specific `class-name` or `id` to the `<a>` and then apply your CSS.